# version updates while updating maven inherited properties

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have multiple maven multi-module projects and one parent project. Parent project pom.xml file is the parent of all other projects' root pom.xml.

```
  -> ParentProject 
     pom.xml

  ->Project1
    -> module1
         src    
         pom.xml
    -> module2 
         src    
         pom.xml
    ->pom.xml

  ->Project2
    -> module1
         src    
         pom.xml
    -> module2 
         src    
         pom.xml
    ->pom.xml
```

In the parent pom.xml file, I have a couple of properties which are inherited and used by others. I need to update those properties quite frequently, and if I increase the version of parent pom after updating those properties, I need to update other poms and increase their versions as well. Is there any way to prevent it, or is there a better way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: First I would ask why you are using properties cause my assumption is that you are using the properties for dependencies. If this is the case I strongly recommend to use a dependencyManagement for that. So you should show example what you are are doing exactly and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [versions](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) plugin to help with the tedium: Update the ParentProject version (and install locally) and then run `mvn versions:update-parent` to update the parent version in Project1 and Project2.

There are other useful targets for updating properties and dependencies.